# how to toggle text color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to toggle text color from red to green and vice versa.

```
<div id="logoup">DEEP</div>
<button id='btn'>CLICK</button>
```

CSS

```
#logoup{
    color:red;
}
.greened{
   color:green;
}
```

JS

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    $('#logoup').toggleClass('greened');
});
```

Doesn't work. Console is empty.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bonaca/9n7s3vph/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use important on *green*, or you could control the coloring using classes, instead of applying it to the element.

#### Method 1: Use `important!` on the greened class

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  $('#logoup').toggleClass('greened');
});
```

```css
#logoup {
  color: red;
}
.greened {
  color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="logoup">DEEP</div>
<button id='btn'>CLICK</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### Method 2: Don't apply color to ID, use classes

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  $('#logoup').toggleClass('red green');
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="logoup" class="red">DEEP</div>
<button id='btn'>CLICK</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I would recommend avoiding `!important` unless absolutely necessary. It leaves no flexibility and this is easily solved without it. [When to use !important](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

Comment: I agree with Derek, there's too many instances where !important can cause problems.  His solution is to improve the specificity of the CSS, so `!important` is not necessary; however, I'd prefer method 2 above, which swaps classes.  If you're looking for something a little more semantic, you could consider using class names like, *default* and *active*, which may include varying degrees of styling (more than just color).

Comment: Agree too. Avoid using !important. Instead, use #logoutp.greened to override properly.

Answer (score 5):

In CSS, an id's defined styles take precedence over an class's defined styles. You can simply attached the class name to the id to fix this without the the need to use `!important` which should only be used as a last resort:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9n7s3vph/6/)

```
#logoup.greened {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: this uses CSS specificity; you could also keep the class generic by performing: `#logoup.greened, .greened { … }`

Answer (score 3):

`id` occupy highers css specificity than `class` . So class wont be able to over rules the styles set by the id. 
Following changes will work

**CSS**

```
.logoup{    // id changed to class
    color:red;
}
.greened{
   color:green;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="logoup" class="logoup">DEEP</div>
<button id='btn'>CLICK</button>
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/d2hh1ezq/4/)

Comment: Can you write over the div rules from js once you've set them?

When I do 

document.getElementsById(strId).style.color = colorOn;

I can't set the color of strId to anything else once it's been set.


document.getElementsById(strId).style.color = colorOff;

Does nothing and I see in console that the colors of colorOn and colorOff are different from one another and the background color of the button.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `id` instead of `class` you must remember about css rules prioritization. The style that has the highest CSS specificity is applied. The specificity of different elements is defined as follows:

```
ID attribute = 100
Class attribute = 10
Element = 1
```

To check this rewrite your css:

```
#logoup{
    color:red;
}
.greened{
   color:green!important;
}
```

Read about [css rule priorities.](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/web/2.3.0/org.tizen.mobile.web.appprogramming/html/guide/w3c_guide/dom_guide/html_priorities_css.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Selector Priority. Override it using `!important;`

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  $('#logoup').toggleClass('greened');
});
```

```css
.greened {
  color: green !important;
}
#logoup {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="logoup">DEEP</div>
<button id='btn'>CLICK</button>
```